# Dragonfruit plant: Is this a fungal disease or is this normal?

Tags: identification, plant-health, plant-care

I see this white scab near the base of this dragon fruit plant:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

The scab hasn't necessarily grown the way I've seen most white mildew or fungus grow. That part isn't soft or mushy either. The new growth looks nice and fresh. So, not sure if the white portion on the bottom is normal for the base of a dragonfruit or if it indicates that the plant is suffering some disease.

I suspected that it could be fungus and have sprayed some copper fungicide as a preventative measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to be fungus, can be bacterial as well.
There are some good descriptions at the Texas Plant-Disease handbook here: https://plantdiseasehandbook.tamu.edu/landscaping/flowers/cacti-and-succulents/

You may take a cutting as high as possible above the infected section. After each cut, see if the you start to see a browned/mushy/rotten interior. Sometimes the infection migrates upwards quickly well before you see anything on the outside - That's a tell-tale sign of pathogens. after each cut it is a good idea to sterilize the knife: If you happen to cut through an infected section, don't do another cut above it (even to remove the infected area) before cleaning and disinfecting the knife. Any cutting exhibiting such discoloration is unworthy of propagation and should be discarded. Only healthy cuttings must be used. It is better to propagate those cuttings under quarantine, away from other plants, in case there is a yet-to-be-noticed infection.